# How to package and deploy a Node/Express Web Application in some NON-CLOUD environment?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, web-deployment

I am a beginner in NodeJS. All the examples seen so far deploy the app in some Cloud environment. Coming from a Java background, deploying app in Jboss, is there anything similar for a Node/Express application ? Or running 'node server.js' is the only way to doit.

Comment: `node server.js` is typical.  You can also look into process managers such as http://nodemon.io/ and http://pm2.keymetrics.io/ Personally I've had node servers up for years at a time with just node server.js running inside tmux

Comment: @generalhenry: thanks for the 'pm2' suggestion. working great for me